# How do I create a python program that also runs a webserver for monitoring purposes

Tags: python, web, webserver

I have a python program that runs a calculation that can take a few days to complete, I was wondering if it was possible for the python program to also run a webserver in another thread or something that I could access locally which I can use to help me monitor the process of the calculation, get other information and maybe even adjust the calculation whilst its running.

I just need to know if this is possible and what the recommended python libraries I need to look into to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up prometheus on your machine and have it track metrics like cpu, disk and memory usage. Also, you can create custom metrics using its python client (https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) and integrate it with a flask app.